# Two action in one button laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

How can I put two actions in one form and one button?

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('shorturl.url.store') }} ">



 first action = {{ route('shorturl.url.store') }}
 second action = {{url('/admin/designs/store')}}
```

When I click on the submit button I want the first action work. if it did it I want to work the second action.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do it in your store function in your controller like this:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  ...
  //after save your model and etc.

  return redirect('/admin/designs/store');
}
```